# Add shipping class under items in New Order email in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, email-notifications

I am trying to add the shipping class under each product to the new order emails for both admin and customers in WooCommerce. This is my first time posting a question so please forgive me if there are formatting issues.

I used the code found here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/291637/woocommerce-add-shipping-class-below-each-product-in-shopping-cart-page

That adds the shipping class below each product in the cart but I want to be able to show it on the order emails also.

I am just unsure of which objects to call to grab the data for each product in the new order email.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_start', 'ts_order_item_meta_start', 10, 4 );
function ts_order_item_meta_start( $item_id, $item, $order, $plain_text, $item_name ){
$product = $cart_item['data']; // Get the WC_Product object instance
$shipping_class_id = $product->get_shipping_class_id(); // Shipping class ID
$shipping_class_term = get_term( $shipping_class_id, 'product_shipping_class' );

if( empty( $shipping_class_id ) )
    return $item_name; // Return default product title (in case of)

$label = __( 'Shipping class', 'woocommerce' );

return $item_name . '<br>
    <p class="item-shipping_class" style="margin:12px 0 0;">
        <strong>' .$label . ': </strong>' . $shipping_class_term->name . '</p>';
}
```

I expected the shipping class to be listed below each product in the "New Order" email but currently adding this code returns an internal server error upon checkout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will display The product shipping class name in Woocommerce "New Order" Email notification:

```
// Setting the email_is as a global variable
add_action('woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 'the_email_id_as_a_global', 1, 4);
function the_email_id_as_a_global($order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ){
    $GLOBALS['email_id_str'] = $email->id;
}

// Display Items shipping class name in New Order email notification
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', 'custom_order_item_name', 10, 3 );
function custom_order_item_name( $item_name, $item, $is_visible ) {
    // Targeting email notifications only
    if( is_wc_endpoint_url() ) return $item_name;

    // Get the WC_Product object (from order item)
    $product = $item->get_product();

    if( $shipping_class_id = $product->get_shipping_class_id() ){
        // Getting the email ID global variable
        $refNameGlobalsVar = $GLOBALS;
        $email_id = $refNameGlobalsVar['email_id_str'];

        // Only for New Order email notification
        if( ! empty($email_id) && 'new_order' === $email_id ) {
            $shipping_class_name = get_term( $shipping_class_id, 'product_shipping_class' )->name;
            $item_name .= '<br><p class="item-shipping_class" style="margin:12px 0 0;">
            <strong>' . __( 'Shipping class', 'woocommerce' ) . ': </strong>' . $shipping_class_name . '</p>';
        }
    }

    return $item_name;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Thank you going to try it now and report back

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you. one last question though if I want to have it show for other email types do I just add that email type into the if statement next to 'new order' ? Asking because I want it to show on the Customer "New Order" email as well as the admin 'New Order' email.

Comment: @JasonShinn There is no  "**Customer** New Order" notification... "New Order" is just related to admin notification.

Comment: I think I got it all figured out, you were an awesome help. Been reading and using alot of the solutions youve had to to others questions on here. Much appreciated! See you around and thanks again!